# Only Create Access but edit and delete using permission set

Tags: profile, security, permission-sets, admin

I have an requirement that profile need to give creating the record but delete and edit access should be done by permission set.

In profile on FLS I gave read and edit acccess to all field or else we couldn't create record. In object level I gave access as read and create but still it is editable in field.

I have attached image of profile Please help me out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Is `Modify All Data` enabled for this profile?

Comment: No I didn't 
In the image I have given only read and create access

Comment: In the screenshot there is `Modify All`, which is not the same permission. [`Modify All Data`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384401&type=1) is a System Permission, while `Modify All` is in the tab of each SObject

Comment: I found what is the issue the permission was working but as I am checking for same record I created it is throwing error and refresh didn't happen properly